# Dynamically create for comprehension of Futures and wait for completion

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have the following code:

```
// Start async functions
val async1: Future[Seq[Int]] = ...
val async2: Future[Seq[Int]] = ...
val async3: Future[Seq[Int]] = ...

// Wait for completion
(for {
    a1 <- async1
    a2 <- async2
    a3 <- async3
} yield (a1, a2, a3)).map {
   // Use the results
}
```

I want to improve this to handle a variable amount of async functions (and not necessarily calling each of them every time).  What I have done so far is:

```
// Start the async functions ?
val asyncs: Seq[Future[Seq[Int]] = otherList.filter(x => someCondition).map(x => asyncFunc(x))

// Wait for the functions to finish ?
(for (seqInt <- asyncs) yield seqInt).map {
    case results => // <-- problem here
        // Use the results 
}
```

The problem I am having is that the results are of type `Future[Seq[Int]]`, but I expected they would be of type `(Seq[Int], Seq[Int], Seq[Int])` like in the first snippet.

---

In the end I would like to do is kickoff a dynamic amount of async functions which all have the same `Future` return type, wait for them all to finish, then use all of their results together.

Comment: `Future.sequence(asyncs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Future.sequence` is the key part I was missing (thanks for the comment)

```
// Create a list of Futures
val asyncs: Seq[Future[Seq[Int]] = otherList.filter(x => someCondition).map(x => asyncFunc(x))

// Use Future.sequence to to execute them and return a list of sequence of integers
Future.sequence(asyncs).map{ 
    case results => // Use the results List[Seq[Int]]
}.recover {
    case error => // Oh no!
}
```